# SSH hostname command on remote server shows hostname of local server

Tags: bash, ssh, hostname

I run this SSH command from server1 on server2 :

```
ssh server2 echo pasword | su - root  -c "echo this is the  `hostname`"
```

I expected the result to be host name of server2 but instead I get host name of server1. How can I manipulate the command to get the hostname of server 2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `su - root` as that command would actually be `sudo su - root`.  Anyway, that command would simply be `ssh server2 'echo "This is the $(hostanme)"'`  And if you're trying to login to it as root it would be `ssh root@server2 'echo "This is the $(hostname)"'`

Comment: it's not that simple,I need to use root on server 2, and strangely if I use sudo with the same root password , it doesn't work, it works only with su - root, but it doesn't show hostname of server 2; in fact "echo" it's just an example , I use a different service, and I have to use `hostname` as a parameter.

Comment: The command `hostname` doesn't need root access.  Any user can use it.  The command you are running on the host you are sshing to needs to be enclosed in single quotes `' '`.

Comment: @AlexP for `sudo`, you use the password of a user who is calling `sudo`,  not the root password. However, neither `su` nor `sudo` will accept password from stdin. If you need to use `sudo`, configure your sudoers file so that the password is not required fro the particular user and command you want to run.

Comment: it works with su also remotely, I put whole output between ' ' .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your command piping is wrong.  As it currently stands this is executed in this order:

1. `ssh server2 echo pasword` - this goes to Server 2 and logs in and executes the command `echo pasword` on the remote system.  (output would be `pasword`)
2. Take the output from #1 ("pasword") and pipe that into this command run locally:

   ```
   su - root -c "echo this is the `hostname`"
   ```

   ... which echoes your LOCAL hostname, technically (and doesn't do anything with the echoed 'pasword' from the first command).  (you don't need 'root' for this though - `hostname` can be run by anyone on the remote system or your local system, no need for superuser!).

What you *need* to do is pass the command into SSH and NOT into pipes this way.  The way to do this is to use this:

```
ssh server2 'echo "This is the $(hostname)"'
```

This will properly send the request to the remote server to get the hostname from *that* server and execute that on the remote server and tell you the response.  *You do not need `sudo` to do this on the remote server*.

If you need to provide a password for the SSH session, you should be using `ssh-pass` instead, and execute this instead:

```
sshpass -p YourPassword ssh server2 'echo "This is the $(hostname)"'
```

This is considered **the proper approach** as it does `keyboard-interactive` authentication non-interactively and passes the password into the SSH command when prompted for a password.  **However this is still very insecure, as your password will be in command history or hardcoded in scripts, so you should consider using SSH Key Authentication on your remote servers instead of password authentication where possible.**

Answer (score 1):

There are several things here.

First - the command

```
ssh server2 echo pasword | su - root  -c "echo this is the  `hostname`"
```

does the following:

- runs the command `echo pasword` on the remote server `server2` via ssh
- and feeds output from this command to the following command, executed on your **local** computer:

  ```
  su - root  -c "echo this is the  `hostname`"
  ```

If you want the entire pipe, starting from `echo`, to be executed on remote computer, you should do it this way:

```
ssh server2 'echo pasword | su - root  -c "echo this is the  `hostname`"'
```

But this is not going to work, because `su` requires to be run from a terminal and will just abort with an error message. However, you don't need root right to run the `hostname` command, so you might just try

```
ssh server2 echo 'this is the  `hostname`'
```

You must enclose the `hostname` substitiution in **single quotes**, otherwise it will be substituted on your local computer before being sent to the remote one, so it will still print your local hostname.

Comment: Just making a note, but this is basically the answer I already wrote... just saying.

Comment: While I was writing my answer, yours wasn't there yet :). When I finished writing it, I saw that there are two.

Comment: it works with su also on remote not only locally, just tested it

Comment: @AlexP the point is you **shouldn't need to use `su` remotely for any reason** - ANY user can run `hostname` to get the current hostname.